# 2 WebViews in one Activity - "variable is already definied" error

Tags: java, android

I have the following question:

I would like to use two webviewer with different URL´s in one activity. 
It always says to me variable is already definied.

```
package com.arved95.dommecraft;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Created by Arved on 07.05.2015.
 */
public class scrennfour extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen4);

        String url ="http://dommecraft.jimdo.com/entbannungsantrag";
        WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        String url ="http://dommecraft.jimdo.com/report";
        WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        }


    }
```

Comment: change the name of the second webview reference to something else

Comment: Like @SarthakMittal said, your declaring the `view` variable twice, how about `WebView firstView`, and `WebView secondView`?

Comment: String url ="http://dommecraft.jimdo.com/entbannungsantrag";
        WebView secondview=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        String url ="http://dommecraft.jimdo.com/report";
        WebView firstview=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

Comment: Now I have errors with view. ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Renaming `url` and `view` variables. like `url1`, 'view1`and`url2`and`view2`. Here you have both value references.
2. Re-Assign `url` and `view` with new values without type information. Here you will lose 1st value references.like

   ```
   String url ="http://dommecraft.jimdo.com/entbannungsantrag";
   WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

   url ="http://dommecraft.jimdo.com/report";
   view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
   ```

> Java Doesn't allow you to declare two variables with same name in one scope.

Comment: @ArvedViehweger It's my pleasure to help to you. Please accept my answer. Thanks :)